# Python - CSS formatting lost when Beautifulsoup4 prettify() on a local .html file

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, beautifulsoup, prettify

I need to edit hundreds of .html files with beautifulSoup 4.

My CSS formatting is lost when I write back the changes to file.

Before `prettify()`:
[image]

And `prettify()`:
[image]

**My code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

files = []
path = r"C:\Files"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.html'):
        files.append(file)

for htmlfile in files:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(htmlfile, encoding="utf-8"), "html.parser")

    soup.header.decompose()
    soup.menu.decompose()

    pretty_html = soup.prettify('utf-8', 'minimal')
    with open(htmlfile, "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.write(pretty_html)
```

If I don't `prettify()` and write is out as below:

```
with open(file, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(soup))
```

I get an encoding error:

```
outfile.write(str(soup))
File "...env\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2192' in position 2027: character maps to <undefined>
```

Seems to be "utf-8" to "cp1252" enconding issue.

I can't wrap my head around this encoding stuff.

Comment: You can make a soup instance using the right encoding that the file is in. Also, you may not need to open the file for writing in binary mode. Or are you looking to convert stored markup to `utf-8` encoding?

Comment: File is in utf-8 encoding and i'm encoding in utf-8 for the soup instance as well.

Comment: Also tried writing without opening in binary format, still get encoding error, see later part of OP.

Comment: Alright, try calling prettify with no formatter e.g. `soup.prettify(formatter=None)`. This should keep strings from being modified . Write the output to file

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help either, css formatting is still lost after writing to file

Comment: Other than taking out the menu and the header, is it a requirement for the document to be prettified? If not, can you share a [Paste](https://pastebin.com) for one of the document for anyone to work with.

Comment: An example url, try to save this to a .html via beautifulsoup and the CSS formatting in the code snippets `<section class="code-listing">` is all lost 

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't really need to prettify() I just want to edit and save the changes to automate thousands of .html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162640/discussion-between-oluwafemi-sule-and-joke4me).